# How can I view my ACTUAL earned YouTube Revenue?

Tags: youtube, google-adsense, youtube-channel

If I go on YouTube under analytics and select revenue, I get a bunch of information on estimated revenue. I want to see the actual revenue and not what is estimated as YouTube does not pay straight from their site, it goes to AdSense.

If I log into AdSense I get the following message:

> YouTube earnings will be added to your AdSense payments page before the 15th of the month and included in your payment if your total earnings exceed the payment threshold. Estimated earnings will not be updated to include your YouTube earnings.

So my YouTube earnings will be in the total paid to me. I want to know what of that total is YouTube, but this line makes it seem like I have no way of finding out: "Estimated earnings will not be updated to include your YouTube earnings." My estimated earnings does not include YouTube.

How can I find out EXACTLY what was actually paid out to me?

Right now it just seems I hope that I'm getting YouTube revenue without knowing if I am or how much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the finalized earnings in AdSense's payment report. You can reach it via Settings > Payments on AdSense.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks! That is what I was looking for.